# Running local python script from remote PHP script

Tags: php, python

I have a local pc 192.168.1.6 (local server) which has my python script and hosting server (remote server for website) which has my php script. How can I run this local python script from a remote PHP script?

I have a working code for running local python script from a local PHP script but I'm not able run local Python script from a remote PHP script.

I have checked other answers but none of them fulfilled my requirements.

Comment: if you want to access remote server you have to establish ssh tunneling foryour local machine and remote server. Have you tried such thing ?

Comment: @myCode means I have to get a static ip for it?

Comment: @myCode dude you don't understand. I want to access and run which is on my local machine from the remote server/hosting. To be exact from a php based website.